# Home Setup with 2 routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dhcp

My ISP router has Wifi integrated in it, but only two physical LAN ports.  I will use one of these ports to connect a TP-Link Archer AC 1900 router also providing Wifi and 4 more LAN ports.  I want to confirm how the setup on both routers needs to be.  Here is what I have now:

1. ISP router 10.0.0.1 has DHCP active
2. TP-Link is connected to ISP router using a LAN port
3. TP-Link 10.0.0.67 has DHCP disabled
4. ISP router wifi is active
5. TP-Link Wifi is active

Is this a viable setup?

If I set ISP router in bridge mode instead and turn on the TP-Link DHCP, will the Wifi on the ISP router still work and use the DHCP of the TP-LINK router?

Comment: What you say can work. I would not use WiFi on the ISP router, just on your stuff, especially if you put the ISP device in Bridge mode. That is the way I do it.

Comment: Thanks John, I wanted to validate my setup, since my internet connection seems to have hickups since I switched to this.  I really would like to keep both WiFi working.

Comment: If you use both WiFi then maybe do not use Bridge Mode or your WiFi devices could land on separate subnets.

Comment: There is only one method to find what will work best with your setup : Try different configurations.

Comment: As soon as I turn on my TP-Link with this setup, the ISP router Wifi starts having problems, connection stops and starts (hickups), that is why I wanted to validate the setup choice.

Comment: Try turning off the ISP WiFi. It that works, you can add another wireless router if you need to (and that can be placed farther away by extending with Ethernet).

Comment: this sounds like both wireless devices are on the same channel. set them to non-conflicting channels in the administration gui and report back